# Partial Page Refresh is not working in Oracle ADF

Tags: jsf, oracle-adf

I have a button in JSF page which when clicked calls a method in the bean and return me all the rows present in the table. But when I am clicking the button the table is not getting refreshed. I am using a return listener in the button and binded the table with it.

```
          <f:facet name="additionalToolbarButtons">
           <af:toolbar>
             <af:commandToolbarButton text="ShowAll"
             actionListener="#{backingBeanScope.Bean.showAllRows}"
             returnListener="#{backingBeanScope.Bean.refreshTable}"/>
           </af:toolbar>
           </f:facet>
```

Table binding -

```
      binding="#{backingBeanScope.Bean.refreshTable}">
```

Java Code -

```
public void refreshTable(ReturnEvent returnEvent) {
    // Add event code here...
    AdfFacesContext ctx = AdfFacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    ctx.addPartialTarget(getRefreshTable());       
}
public RichTable getRefreshTable() {
    return refreshTable;
}
```

When I am manually refreshing the page then I can see all the rows in table. I have recently started working in ADF. Can someone please guide me

Comment: Did you try printing or debugging on getRefreshTable(), is it returning object reference or null?
Also try to get UIComponent from id of table, and use that in partial target

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Reload ADF table after button click in a Fusion Web application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66418328/reload-adf-table-after-button-click-in-a-fusion-web-application)

Answer (score 0):

Which exact version of JDev you are using?

Try to ppr the parent of the table.

Comment: I am using the 12C jdev..I tried doing the parent table PPR but still no luck